# How to count lines between tags?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an `HTML` formatted file that looks something like this:

```
<ENDBLOCK>
#Comment 1
Content 1
Content 2
<ENDBLOCK>
#Comment 2
#Content 3
<ENDBLOCK>
#Comment 3
Content 4
Content 5
<ENDBLOCK>

<ENDBLOCK>
```

I need to do 2 things:

1. How to count the number of lines between each `<ENDBLOCK>`?  In this example, the result total_lines = 3, 2, 3, 1 where the last set of ` is 1 because there is a carriage return.
2. How to count the number of lines between each `<ENDBLOCK>` that starts with `#`?  In this example comment_lines = 1, 2, 1, 0

Basically, I need to check if the total number of lines for each `<ENDBLOCK>` equals the number of lines of comment.  If they equal, then print out something.

Here's what I currently have:

```py
char_count = 0
with open('10230_13.html', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#'): # not sure how to do this between <ENDBLOCK>
            comment_count += len(line)
        if lines (between ENDBLOCK): # not sure how to do this between <ENDBLOCK>
            total_lines +=len(lines)

    if comment_count == total_lines:
    print("Fail")
```

Comment: Half the point of HTML (or other XML-like formats) is that whitespace is not supposed to matter. Why are you trying to count lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work, although it reads in all of the data at once.

```py
with open('10230_13.html', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

chunks = data.split("<ENDBLOCK>\n")
chunk_sizes = [chunk.count("\n") for chunk in chunks]
chunk_pound_numbers = [chunk.count("\n#") for chunk in chunks]
```